# solaris 10 tail variable lines

Tags: bash, variables, solaris

I previously used ksh for this script.  I would create the variable like say  `LINE=8` and then use `tail -$LINE <file>` and everything was great.  Now I am trying to rewrite this in bash, but still in Solaris 10 bash.  No matter how I write this tail line in bash, it is not using the value of the variable:

`tail -$LINE <file>`    = "tail: cannot open input"

`tail -${LINE} <file>`  = "tail: cannot open input"

Anyone have an idea how to cite the variable correctly in Solaris 10 bash so this works correctly?

Comment: it would be a good idea to include your bash script in your post or maybe just the few lines around the `tail` part.  For example, `<file>` is an actual file name??

Comment: All variables consisting of purely upper-case letters, e.g. `$LINE`, are reserved for `bash` itself. You may be clashing with something. Maybe try lower-case or a mixture.

Comment: which tail are you using? `/usr/bin/tail` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/tail`?

Comment: What version of bash is "Solaris 10 bash" -> `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`

Comment: I suggest to use `tail -n $LINE file`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `cat` and pipe it to `tail`:

```
cat <filename> | tail -${LINE}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get this if the LINE variable contains non-digits: on my Mac

```
$ LINE=8
$ tail -$LINE .bashrc
[expected contents]
```

But if add a carriage return to the variable

```
$ LINE=$'8\r'
$ tail -$LINE .bashrc
tail: option used in invalid context -- 8
```

Check your script file for `\r\n` line endings.